# Collecting the returned HashMaps into one with new identifier in Java-8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I'm not well versed with Java Stream collector framework, I want to solve a real world problem and want to use streams.

Here is simplified hypothetical scenario of the actual problem.

I have an interface whose implementations return a `HashMap<Integer, Object>`

```
interface myInterface{
  String getImplKey(); //just adding it for classification.
  Map<Integer, Object> getImplDataWithDataKeys(); //this is main functionality but different implementations. 
}
```

Now if I auto wire this interface list in spring, spring will provide all the implementation in one place

I want to write a code where I can collect the data from all the implementations and return into a HashMap, Map will also tell which implementation the data belongs to.

```
List<myInterface> myinterfaceImpls;

getAll Data(){
        myinterfaceImpls.stream()..... 
       call myInterfaceImpl.getDataWithDataKeys() ... 
       collect into Map with myInterface.getIdentifierKey() as key. and above myInterfaceImpl.getDataWithDataKeys() as value
get something in form Map<String,Map<Integer,Object>>
```

Comment: `myinterfaceImpls.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(myInterface::getImplKey,myInterface::getImplDataWithDataKeys));`

Comment: How about if I want to just flatten the result of all Impls in one single hashmap.
 myinterfaceImpls.stream()..... 
       call myInterfaceImpl.getDataWithDataKeys() ..return all result on one hashmap

Comment: Then what is key in the single map? and do you want to merge all implementations?

Comment: no, actually you see all implementations are already returning Map<Integer,Obj>, Something changed and now I just wanted all the result in one big map.  what I did was `Map<int,String> combinedData = new HashMap<>(); myinterfaceImpls.forEach(e-> combinedData.putAll(e.getDataWithDataKeys()) ); it works but is a sequential execution. every implementation wait for other to fetch Data, until other finishes. With streams it could've been done parallel, but I'm new to streams, Also do you recommend any good Book ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, based on your comment you can do like this:

```
myinterfaceImpls.stream()
                 .flatMap(myImpl->myImpl.getDataWithDataKeys().entrySet().stream())
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue));
```

However, if your concern is about a duplicate key, you can perform [`toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) collector with a merge function.

Comment: as soon as I do a flatMap i get `Cannot infer type argument(s) for <R> flatMap(Function<? super T,? extends Stream<? extends R>>)`

Comment: as soon as I do a flatMap i get `Cannot infer type argument(s) for <R> flatMap(Function<? super T,? extends Stream<? extends R>>)`  I guess because the first stream I started is a Stream from List of InterfacesImpl whereas the myImpl.getDataWithKey returns the Map<Int,Object>

Comment: It wont work, You cant stream a Map. `The method stream() is undefined for the type 
Map<String,Object>` Actually the result from myImpls.getDataWithDataKey is of type Map<String,Object>  ... Kept Map value as Object because sometime result is a List sometime just a String... Looking for doing in stream, as in case of duplicate KEYS I want to merge the two lists, I'm trying to avoid nested loops

Comment: Awesome, Now how do I merge the Lists which can be in value, if keys matches. 
The Map value is Object, can be a String or a List of Strings... In case of Collision it will always be a List, and want to merge it

Comment: in this case you should have third argument as a merge function.

Comment: I added List::addAll as the third arg in collectors.toMap, but as my Map type is Map<String,Object> its an error `Description Resource Path Location Type
The type List does not define addAll(Object, Object) that is applicable`  is there a way to tpe cast here

Comment: In worst case I can change my interface to return `Map<String, List<Strings>> ` and and will return the one element List whereever I was returning String.. But is there a cleaner solution

Comment: yeah you can do it. since it is verbose, try to define a function and check it instance then use addAll method.

Comment: your idea would be clean. just for single string use new ArrayList (Collections.singletoneList (s))